# Why my Ubuntu 12.10 can't recognize Canon IP1980?

Tags: 12.10, printing, canon

I've tried installing the required package from Canon Europe, but when I go to CUPS 1.6.1, and I click *"Add new printer"* it keep saying:

> No printer found

Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Before you install the package from canon you need to install [libcupsys2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/nl/quantal/libcupsys2). Download it and use Ubuntu Software Center to install it. Then download the driver from the Canon here with Debian as operating system: http://software.canon-europe.com/products/0010647.asp

Use a terminal to go to the directory where this file is saved and extract the file (I assume ~/Downloads/) and do ...

```
cd ~/Downloads/
tar xvf iP1900_debian_printer.tar
cd iP1900_debian_printer/
sudo dpkg-i *.deb
sudo apt-get-f install
```

and the printer should work.

Last time I used this was in 2011 so please leave feedback if it does not anymore.